# New lead Button added from Quick Action on contact object should pre-populating contact info

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

New to coding and wanted this functionality the requirement is I have Added a New Lead Button from Quick Action on Contact Object want the information when the button is clicked the "contact info" will be pre-populated from the selected contact.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. You'l need to show some research to get Community assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating the Quick Action, open it, then scroll down to the **Predefined Field Values** section. There you can add pre-defined values to the fields you selected.